# Polymerfire query orderByChild not working

Tags: data-binding, firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

`orderByChild` is not documented but is part of the public api of the query element from [polymerfire](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire).

I have something like this in my app:

```
<firebase-query
  id="query"
  orderByChild="[[order]]"
  path="/records/[[user.uid]]"
  data="{{records}}">
</firebase-query>
```

where `order` is property of my element that has a valid string.

The query is running and returning results, but without the sorting.

From inspecting it in chrome, the problem is that `query.orderByChild` is not being bound. If I assign it from the chrome console (`query.orderByChild = myelement.order`) it re-runs the query and return the records in the correct order.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a way to change the sort order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to dasherize your property:

```
<firebase-query id="query" order-by-child="[[order]]"></firebase-query>
```

Any time you see camel case in Polymer property definitions, you should convert to dash case when actually writing the element.

Comment: No matter the framework I'm using, I always waste a few hours because of this. Thanks!

Comment: Hours? I've wasted days trying to figure this one out.  Thank you